# Windows Markdown editor with auto-bulleting lists

Tags: windows, markdown, markup

I'm looking a text editor on Windows that can handle Markdown syntax. Specifically, I would like it to automatically insert bullets when adding to a bulleted list (so I don't have to manually type the asterisk at the beginning of each line).

For example, this behavior is available in Byword for Mac, but I need this same functionality in a Windows app. Ideally this is a standalone app but I'm okay with locally running web-based solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try sublime text 3 with [Markdown Edit](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing).
This is the [Features](https://github.com/SublimeText-Markdown/MarkdownEditing#features) list on the Github. Bullets are addressed in the third point.

> At the end of a list item, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will automatically insert the new list item bullet.
>
> > Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> on the blank list item will indent it and switch the list bullet to another one (Order is *, -, + in a cycle).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Visual Studio 20xx (the Express version is free) with this addon:

Markdown Mode - http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0855e23e-4c4c-4c82-8b39-24ab5c5a7f79

Comment: Unfortunately Visual Studio 2010 Express does not support Extensions. I found this out when trying to install this very extension. For something independent, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Extensibility) "Extensions are supported in the Standard (and higher) versions of Visual Studio 2005. Express Editions do not support hosting extensions."

Answer (score 0):

[Markdown Edit](http://markdownedit.com/) automatically insert bullets.

Here is an example gif of the bullets being added:

[image: bullets]

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain why this particular software? Maybe include a screenshot of the behaviour the OP is after?

Comment: @Burgi this function is not specified in the [features](http://markdownedit.com/features). But I made a [gif](http://i.imgur.com/RLG1uki.gif)